# Websockets Chat application - how to incorporate user types

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have created a basic websockets chat application where every user can talk amongst themselves however the purpose of the chat is for the clients to talk only with staff members. I have a user modal which has a staff boolean tag which determines whether the user is staff or not.

code for the Websockets:

```
// Make Connection Chat component 

var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");



$(document).ready(function() {
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    var name = document.getElementById('nameOfClient');
    $('.modal').on( 'click',"#send", function() {
        socket.emit('chat',{
            message:  message.value,
            name: name.value
        });
    });
    // 'is typing' message
    message.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
        socket.emit('typing',{
           name: name.value 
        });
    });
 });

// listen
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    console.log("In socket on chat");
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.name + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>'; 

});

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    console.log("In typing on chat");
    output.innerHTML = "<p><em>" + data.name + " is typing</em></p>";
})
```

Anyone know the best way to implement this.

EDIT
I'm looking for a basic implementation at the start where any client can talk to any staff member and they can talk simultaneously.

Comment: On the server side, you can store the client sockets in one array and store the staff sockets in another array, That way you can selectively send messages to staff or clients as required

Comment: I think what you're asking is going to be really complex. The question needs more information. Are you asking how to pair staff members with a single client? How will staff replies be filtered down to the client that sent the message? What is your scope on this project? The simplest answer would be to create a chat backend that connects a single client to a single staff member, and that is still really complex.

Comment: What I did on my websocket chat was create a random, unique token upon user login and insert that into the database. Then on socket new connection, verify token with database and have the database return user rights. After that you can just keep a user object within your websocket so you don't have to query your database all the time.

Comment: @JoelTrauger At this stage i just want a way only clients can talk to staff accounts. It can be any client talking to any staff member

Comment: As said before: What you want isn't actually that complicated if you understand how to do it. But it is if you don't. Your backend assigns an object with a unique id to each connected client. When one clients sends a message, your backend relays that message to all other clients. The trick is to gain control over this. You can assign properties to those objects (staff property). Then instead of relaying to all clients, only relay to clients with that property. It's basicly just controlling who can read the message and who not (private chat / seperate rooms)

Comment: @icecub Thanks for the help, yeah it's my first time using websockets so probably slightly more complicated than it should be.

Comment: Using a framework / library makes your life a lot easier. But if you don't understand how it works, it also limits what you can do with it. I would start by "debugging" your websocket. Just print out the default objects / variables so you understand what kind of data is in there. Learn how to manipulate that. Then move on from there. You'll see that once you understand it, it's not that complicated anymore and you'll be able to turn it into a full featured chatsystem any way you like.